# How to use STOPSIGNAL instruction within Docker?

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-compose, docker-registry, dockerhub

I have installed Docker 1.9 and want to know if I am using the instruction in the right way.

> FROM internal.docker.registry/image1
>   MAINTAINER internal@abc.com
>   COPY sample.war webapps/sample.war
>   STOPSIGNAL SIGKILL

My understanding is that when I do

> docker stop container_id

, it will stop the  tomcat that is running within container. It will also delete the Pid file.

Please verify if I have the correct understanding.

Answer (score 7):

A `SIGKILL` is a signal which stops the process immediately, without letting the process exit cleanly, so `SIGKILL` will not allow Tomcat to shutdown gracefully and remove it's PID file.

`SIGTERM` and `SIGINT` both tell Tomcat to run the shutdown hook (deleting the PID file) and shutting down gracefully.

`SIGTERM` is equivalent to running `kill <pid>` and is also the default for docker.

`SIGINT` is equivalent to pressing `ctrl-C`.